# What kind of mastic/putty is used for threaded metal plumbing connections?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

[image]

Whatever is used here is leaking very slightly (like a couple of water drops here and there ),  and I'm curious what  kind of mastic/putty is used for this purpose. I guess I need to replace it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe dope on threaded drain pipe.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a connection to a trap from the main drain line. There should be no mastic or pipe dope on this connection. There should be a flat washer on top of the trap or tucked into the nut on the incoming drain connection. Tightening with a pair of Chanellocks or adjustable pliers should be all that's needed. Take it apart and clean it up and make sure there's a good washer in there. You can get the washers at your home store

Comment: thanks for the  advice